# If $p^{a} \mid\mid n$, and $n$ is not a perfect square, can $n$ be a square modulo all powers of $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

We have an integer $n$ which is not a perfect square and $p^{a} \mid\mid n$ for some $a \geq 1$. I was wondering if $n$ can be a square modulo all powers of $p$?

My strong feeling is that the answer is NO but how do I prove it?

Comment: Any restrictions on $p$? Instead of stating in the comments, consider stating them in the question body. If "all powers of $p$" literally means all powers of $p$, we have $p^k > n$ for some $k$, and $n$ not a perfect square. What then?

Comment: Are they? The nonstandard definition of $\Vert$, whether $n$ can be negative, and whether $p,a$ are even positive integers are all not stated clearly.

Comment: On second thoughts, this could be a deeper question concerning quadratic residues, and [a section of Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_power_modulus) could have something to do with it.

Comment: What is the meanng of the double divide bar operator here?

Comment: @AdamL Usually $p^a||n$ means that $p^a|n$ but $p^{a+1}\nmid n$. We say $p^a$ exactly divides $n$.

Comment: Great thanks I hadn't seen it before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible if $a$ is even (and impossible if $a$ is odd). For example $-25$ is a square modulo all powers of $5$ (use Hensel’s lemma).

This condition is equivalent to asking whether $n$ is a square in the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Answer (score 0):

From the binomial series for $(1+z)^{1/2}$ we get $$-100 = 5^2 (1-5)= (5\sum_{k=0}^l {1/2 \choose k} (-5)^k)^2 \bmod 5^l$$ where $1/2$ means an inverse of $2 \bmod 5^l$

Hensel lemma is its generalization.